# I entered the wrong radio security code, now I'm locked out

Tags: honda, accord

Hi is there anybody that can help me ?

I entered the wrong radio security code for my 2009 Honda Accord. Now the screen shows, "Error E". I found the right code, but won't let me enter the code. If someone knows what I should do, it would be appreciated :)

Comment: It would help a lot if you could clarify where you entered the wrong code (and if you know it, what the wrong code was) and what you were trying to achieve when you entered the code. Also tell us what, if anything you've done since entering the wrong code.

Answer (score 5):

If cycling the key doesn't work, pull fuse number 15 in the underdash fuse box and re-insert. Re-enter the radio code. You have 10 tries to do this correctly before you are permanently locked out. Then you will be required to go to a dealer and have the unit reset or replaced.